# ironpython elementtree, illegal character in content

Tags: ironpython, elementtree, illegal-characters

I'm trying to parse a xml document from wolframalpha.

The coding im using now is:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import urllib
import urllib2

def ask(s=None):
    q = urllib.urlencode(dict(input=s, appid='apikey'))
    url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?' + q
    r = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    p = ET.parse(r)

ask('what is the distance from montreal to New York?')
```

I get a error with illegal character in content. While it works flawless with normal python.

This is the xml: http://pastebin.com/ektp23bN

Using ironpython 2.7.4. .Net 4.0 32bit

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you are describing.
There seems to be a difference in the `ElementTree` and `xmllib` implementation shipped with IronPython 2.7.4 when compared to CPython 2.7.4/2.7.6 and you could/should probably [file a bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/create) for that.

You could be able to work around the issue by explicitly decoding utf-8:

```py
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = r.read().decode('utf-8')
p = ET.fromstring(data)
```